Connecting Blue Yeti usb microphone to Android tablet?
How do you select audio input/output devices on an Android tablet (e.g. galaxy tab) so you can use a Blue Yeti USB mic as an input device but NOT as an output device?
The Blue Yeti has headphone jacks, for some odd reason, so when I connect it to my tablet, it auto detects the mic and uses it to record sound. However, since it also has headphone jacks, it automatically tries to use it to output sound as well.
I want to use this mic to improve audio quality during Zoom calls, but I still want it to output sound over the tablet's speakers. How do I do that?
Currently, it seems to randomly select if it outputs sound over the speakers or the Yeti's headphones. Frustratingly, unlike Linux or Windows, Android doesn't seem to have any kind of audio I/O management screen, so I can't simply manually select the output device.

Most Android implementations have an audio section in settings.
